# Excel Formula for Solving backcasting growth

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a time series of data in excel and am missing the first few years of the time series but I have the y/y growth rates for the period and I'm trying to solve for the missing values. If is was calculating growth moving forward, I could simply multiply the growth rate times the value of the preceding period and add that to the value in the preceding period =(F2*G3)+F2

[image: see attached].

But I don't have the preceding period so I need to grow it backwards based on the values I do have (ie, 2016).  What excel formula would I use to solve for the missing values?

Comment: In `F5`, `=F6/(G6+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question out, in `F5`, put `=F6/(G6+1)` and drag up:

[image]